# Can not use action tag in a vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforcedx

There was something wrong with my page when I add an action tag to it. Don't know what went wrong. By the way I'm using this page in community site(CloudCraze).
(There is nothing in the page yet)The code of the page was like this:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" controller="controller"
    action="{!initAction}">
</apex:page>
```

The code of the controller :

```
public class controller{
    public controller() {
    }
    public PageReference initAction() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!!!!

Comment: whats the problem are you getting some error or you just can't use action ?

Comment: @User6670 It shows "Site_Error2". I figured it was because I used this page in CloudCraze, looks like it does not support action tag.